# Variable not working inside an if statement when used in a for loop with enabledelayedexpansion

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I have a text file with MS Windows update names:

```
...
KB3072019
KB3044374
KB3011780
KB3083711
...
```

And having a folder with

[image: downloaded updates]

:

My goal is to check wether an update is downloaded or not according to the text file.

```
@echo off
set /a x=0
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (d:\WindowsUpdate.log) do (
set /a x=x+1
echo Update number !x!, name %%A, state:
IF EXIST d:\!Del\Win8Updates_x64\Merged\*%%A*.cab (echo Downloaded) ELSE (echo MISSING!)
)
pause
```

The output should be like this:

```
Update number 83, name KB3045999, state:
MISSING
Update number 84, name KB3045746, state:
Downloaded
Update number 85, name KB3066441, state:
Downloaded
Update number 86, name KB3071663, state:
MISSING
```

But actually it looks like this:

```
Update number 83, name KB3045999, state:
MISSING
Update number 84, name KB3045746, state:
MISSING
Update number 85, name KB3066441, state:
MISSING
Update number 86, name KB3071663, state:
MISSING
```

My question: why does %%A not work inside the if statement?

**Important:** I don't want to skip the line numbers, because they're representing the order of the updates. Later I'll modify the script to copy/move the existing updates to another location prefixed with it's order number, like *83_windows8.1-kb3045999-x64.cab*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a path containing an exclamation mark, `d:\!Del`, which causes the problem, because when delayed expansion is enabled, the `!` is removed. This is also true for the echoed text `MISSING!`. Removing `@echo off` temporarily will allow you to see that behaviour when examining the output.

To avoid that, there are (at least) the following options:

1. Escaping exclamation marks:

   ```
   @echo off
   set /A x=0
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (d:\WindowsUpdate.log) do (
       set /A x+=1
       echo Update number !x!, name %%A, state:
       if exist "d:\^!Del\Win8Updates_x64\Merged\*%%A*.cab" (
           echo Downloaded
       ) else (
           echo MISSING^^!
       )
   )
   endlocal
   pause
   ```
2. Disabling delayed expansion temporarily:

   ```
   @echo off
   set /A x=0
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (d:\WindowsUpdate.log) do (
       set /A x+=1
       echo Update number !x!, name %%A, state:
       setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
       if exist "d:\!Del\Win8Updates_x64\Merged\*%%A*.cab" (
           echo Downloaded
       ) else (
           echo MISSING!
       )
       endlocal
   )
   endlocal
   pause
   ```
3. Enabling delayed expansion only where needed:

   ```
   @echo off
   set /A x=0
   setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

   for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (d:\WindowsUpdate.log) do (
       set /A x+=1
       setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
       echo Update number !x!, name %%A, state:
       endlocal
       if exist "d:\!Del\Win8Updates_x64\Merged\*%%A*.cab" (
           echo Downloaded
       ) else (
           echo MISSING!
       )
   )
   endlocal
   pause
   ```

Comment: Great, thank you very much, removing or replacing `!` with `^!` solved the problem! I definitely need to stop using exclamation marks in my code. :)